# Binding list of nested viewmodels on post ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have the following viewmodel structure:
ItemViewModel containing a property Model of type BaseViewModel.

In this concrete example, Model is of type WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel. This viewmodel in turns consists of an IEnumerable of type ManagerWorkScheduleViewModel.

Inside the ItemView.cshtml the following is used:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="@Model.FormName" name="@Model.FormName" onsubmit="@Model.OnSubmitFunction">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model, Model.ItemViewName + "View")
    </div>
    <button class="btn pull-left" type="submit" style="margin: 2px;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
        @Model.ViewConfiguration.SaveText @Model.ItemTitle
     </button>
 </form>
```

I have omitted some details (basically a bunch of if's determining whether or not to add CRUD buttons. The Model.ItemViewName is the typename (in this case its WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel).

```
public class WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{ 
    [HiddenInput]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput]
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ManagerWorkScheduleViewModel> WorkSchedules { get; set; } 
}
```

The WeekManagerWorkScheduleView.cshtml looks like this:

```
@using DRSTransportPortal.ViewModels
@model WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Ugentlig arbejdsplan - ledere";
}

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RegionId)

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th><b>Leder</b></th>
           <th><b>Uge</b></th>
           <th><b>Mandag</b></th>
           <th><b>Tirsdag</b></th>
           <th><b>Onsdag</b></th>
           <th><b>Torsdag</b></th>
           <th><b>Fredag</b></th>
           <th><b>Lørdag</b></th>
           <th><b>Søndag</b></th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th></th>
              @foreach (var date in Model.Dates)
              {
                  <th><i><small>@date.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")</small></i></th>
              }
       </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.WorkSchedules)
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a view called ManagerWorkScheduleViewModel.cshtml residing in Views/imalazysod/EditorTemplates (MVC knows this location, as I am using a custom view engine, derived from Razor):

```
@using DRSTransportPortal.ViewModels
@model ManagerWorkScheduleViewModel
<tr id="@Model.Id">
    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ManagerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control editoritem" } })</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateWeekText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control editoritem" } })</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MondayCodeChoice, new { @class = "form-control editoritem" })</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TuesdayCodeChoice, new { @class = "form-control editoritem" })</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.WednesdayCodeChoice, new { @class = "form-control editoritem" })</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ThursdayCodeChoice, new { @class = "form-control editoritem" })</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FridayCodeChoice, new { @class = "form-control editoritem" })</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SaturdayCodeChoice, new { @class = "form-control editoritem" })</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SundayCodeChoice, new { @class = "form-control editoritem" })</td>
 </tr>
```

The "Choice" properties are all of type ChoiceViewModel using a ChoiceViewModel.cshtml.

Now, everything renders fine:
[Screenshot (names omitted). Red box indicates 1 (one) nested viewmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl8jK.png)

The generated HTML looks like this (only the first row and first few cells are shown here):

```
<tr id="134">
    <td><input name="Model.WorkSchedules[0].Id" id="Model_WorkSchedules_0__Id" type="hidden" value="134" data-val-required="Feltet Id skal udfyldes." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number."></td>
    <td>OMITTED</td>
    <td>2016 - 36</td>
    <td>
    <select name="Model.WorkSchedules[0].MondayCodeChoice.SelectedValue" class="form-control editoritem dropdown" id="SelectChoices" onchange="">
       <option value="1">06:00 - 14:00</option>
       <option value="19">06:00 - 18:00</option>
       <option value="31">08:00 - 16:00</option>
       <option value="2">10:00 - 18:00</option>
       <option value="32">10:00 - 18:00</option>
       <option value="23">Bagvagt</option>
       <option value="22">Ferie</option>
       <option value="8">Fri</option>
       <option value="3">Kontor</option>
       <option value="15">Kussus</option>
       <option value="16">Syg</option>
     </select>
   </td>  
REST OF HTML IS OMMITTED (CONTINUES FOR 12 ROWS WITH 10 CELLS EACH)
</tr>
```

However, when I post back (using jQuery, ajax btw) this is what I get:
[Controller breakpoint, after modelbinding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4fbF.png)

I have tried putting in a custom modelbinder on the BaseViewModel, and debugging that haven't seen anything that doesn't look alright. It resolves the correct types (WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel, etc.).
Using that, my Forms element from ControllerContext->...->Request is:
{Model.Id=141&ModelType=DRSTransportPortal.ViewModels.WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel%2c+DRSTransportPortal%2c+Version%3d1.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3dnull&Model.RegionId=1&Model.WorkSchedules%5b0%5d.Id=134&Model.WorkSchedules%5b0%5d.MondayCodeChoice.SelectedValue=22&Model.WorkSchedules%5b0%5d.TuesdayCodeChoice.SelectedValue=1&Model.WorkSchedules%5b0%5d.WednesdayCodeChoice.SelectedValue=1&Model.WorkSchedules%5b0%5d.ThursdayCodeChoice.SelectedValue=1&Model.WorkSchedules%5b0%5d.FridayCodeChoice.SelectedValue=1&Model.WorkSchedules%5b0%5d.SaturdayCodeChoice.SelectedValue=1&Model.WorkSchedules%5b0%5d.SundayCodeChoice.SelectedValue=1&..... CONTINUES FOR ALL 12 NESTED VIEWMODELS}

I have made sure the following is true:
All bindings are made to properties (default ie. {get;set;})
No viewmodels, including BaseViewModel, have constructors (ie. default constructors should be created)
All properties and classes are public

So...my question is, why is the modelbinder unable to create the viewmodels of the list? I have no problem using the template elsewhere, editing pr. person, ie. one row at a time). 
Yes, I know there are MANY questions and MANY answers related to MVC modelbinding, but none seem to quite fall into this category (same goes for books). What really puzzles me, is that it is recognized that a list of 12 items is needed, but it just isn't populated.

EDIT:

```
public class BaseViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ModelType");
        var type = Type.GetType((string) typeValue.ConvertTo(typeof (string)), true);
        if(!typeof(BaseViewModel).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("NOT A BASEVIEWMODEL");

        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);
        return model;
    }
}

[ModelBinder(typeof(BaseViewModelBinder))]
public class BaseViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime Edited { get; set; }
    public virtual string SelectionName { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public override async Task<JsonResult> Save(ItemViewModel item, string parentName, int? parentId)
    {
        if (item?.Model == null)
        {
            const int result = 0;
            return Json(new { result });
        }
        var model = item.Model as WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel;
        if (model == null)
        {
            const int result = 0;
            return Json(new { result });
        }

        foreach (var inner in model.WorkSchedules)
        {

        }
        return await base.Save(item, parentName, parentId);
    }

public class ManagerWorkScheduleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Leder")]
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int? DateWeekId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("År / Uge")]
    public string DateWeekText { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int? MondayCodeId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ChoiceViewModel")]
    [DisplayName("Mandag")]
    public ChoiceViewModel MondayCodeChoice { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int? TuesdayCodeId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ChoiceViewModel")]
    [DisplayName("Tirsdag")]
    public ChoiceViewModel TuesdayCodeChoice { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int? WednesdayCodeId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ChoiceViewModel")]
    [DisplayName("Onsdag")]
    public ChoiceViewModel WednesdayCodeChoice { get; set; }


    [HiddenInput]
    public int? ThursdayCodeId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ChoiceViewModel")]
    [DisplayName("Torsdag")]
    public ChoiceViewModel ThursdayCodeChoice { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int? FridayCodeId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ChoiceViewModel")]
    [DisplayName("Fredag")]
    public ChoiceViewModel FridayCodeChoice { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int? SaturdayCodeId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ChoiceViewModel")]
    [DisplayName("Lørdag")]
    public ChoiceViewModel SaturdayCodeChoice { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public int? SundayCodeId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("ChoiceViewModel")]
    [DisplayName("Søndag")]
    public ChoiceViewModel SundayCodeChoice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh, btw, using ASP.NET MVC 5 ( I think..the one BEFORE Core :))

Comment: You cannot use a derived class. You have not shown the relevant code (your models or the controller methods, but if property `Model` is type of `BaseViewModel`, then the `DefaultModelBinder` will initialize `BaseViewModel`, not `WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel` and any properties of `WeekManagerWorkScheduleViewModel` that are not in `BaseViewModel` will be ignored

Comment: If I put a break point inside the modelbinder it does use the correct model, also, all properties (that have hidden inputs) on the top level model ARE correctly created and given correct value. Also, it works like a charms for all viewmodels derived from BaseViewModel that dont have nested viewmodels needed in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, stupid me.
I forgot how I actually made this framework to begin with.

I created this mainly for CRUD operations, so I only need to define viewmodel (derived from BaseViewModel), view, repository and dto types for each business entity as well as an empty controller. Then everything else is using a standard set of controllers (three levels of derivation, depending on functionality needed) and all I need to do is create a config entry for the business entity, defining the vm, view, repo types as well as some CRUD options for buttons and labels.
All top level viewmodels and view are the same, like ItemView, ItemViewModel, ItemListView, SingleSelector, MultipleSelector etc etc.

What I had FORGOTTEN was that I limited myself to one business entity at a time, hence outputting the class (see the modelbinder), so I COULD use derived viewmodels...this works great, except obviously in this case.

What happens is, as the binding tries to populate the list, it keeps trying to populate it using the first viewmodel type (as this is the only one known after POST) and not the derived. DAMMIT! So back to the drawing table (no nesting :( )

Comment: Solved by adding a static dictionary of custom modelbinders which are used instead of the default library modelbinder (the one from the question). So now, in the few places I DO need nested viewmodels, I can. Without contaminating my shared library with any dependencies. :)